# Dispatcher not triggered during Myo hub initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, dispatcher, myo

I'm porting initialization code for a Myo armband to a WPF application, that uses a C# wrapper, http://goo.gl/HfwqQe to interact with the device.

But when I add the initialization code under the `InitializeComponent();` in the code behind of my user control, the line to update a textbox with connection status is never triggered, `this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>`

I debugged this by setting a breakpoint on the line just before the dispatcher code and this is being called `hub.MyoConnected += (sender, e) =>` meaning that the Myo has connected, but the following `dispatcher` line after that updates the `statusTbx`is never called and skipped over.

Anyone have any idea here what could be causing this?

I'm not sure why it won't output the connection status to the textbox. The same code worked before but this is a new version of the C# wrapper I'm using.

The console samples work fine, http://goo.gl/RFHLym and output connection to console, but I can't get it to output the connection to textbox instead.

This is the complete code for getting the Myo arm band's connection status :

```
using MyoSharp.Communication;
using MyoSharp.Device;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MyoTestv4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProductsView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AdductionAbductionFlexionView : UserControl
    {
        public AdductionAbductionFlexionView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            // create a hub that will manage Myo devices for us
            using (var channel = Channel.Create(ChannelDriver.Create(ChannelBridge.Create())))
            using (var hub = Hub.Create(channel))
            {
                 //set a bpoint here, gets triggered
                // listen for when the Myo connects
                hub.MyoConnected += (sender, e) =>
                {
                     //set a bpoint here, doesn't get triggered
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        statusTbx.Text = "Myo has connected! " + e.Myo.Handle;
                        //Console.WriteLine("Myo {0} has connected!", e.Myo.Handle);
                        e.Myo.Vibrate(VibrationType.Short);

                    }));
                };

                // listen for when the Myo disconnects
                hub.MyoDisconnected += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        statusTbx.Text = "Myo has disconnected!";
                        //Console.WriteLine("Oh no! It looks like {0} arm Myo has disconnected!", e.Myo.Arm);
                        e.Myo.Vibrate(VibrationType.Medium);
                    }));
                };

                // start listening for Myo data
                channel.StartListening();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `using (var hub = Hub.Create(channel))`?  `hub` is destroyed immediately after `channel.StartListening();`.

Comment: Remove the using clauses and try again, see if it works.

Comment: @kennyzx when I remove the using clauses, I get errors on `hub` and `channel` as they can't be found.

Comment: I mean remove the `using` keyword. `using` means the object is disposable and its Dispose() method is called at the end of using bracket. So the event is not fired. just call `var channel = Channel.Create(ChannelDriver.Create(ChannelBridge.Create());`

Comment: @kennyzx I removed this keyword before the two lines of code, but I get errors, `var and hub doesn't exist` and `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Comment: okay just seen your answer, I'll try this and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `channel` and `hub` are disposed immediately after calling

```
channel.StartListening();
```

`using` is a convenient way to dispose object for you, in this case, this is not desired. Please refer to [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.120).aspx) for more info.

Try these steps to fix the problem. 1. Declare channel and hub as private field of the class. 2. Do not use `using` keyword. 3. Remember to dispose `hub` and `channel` when `AdductionAbductionFlexionView` is disposed of.

```
public partial class AdductionAbductionFlexionView : UserControl
{
    IChannel channel;
    IHub hub;

    public AdductionAbductionFlexionView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // create a hub that will manage Myo devices for us
        channel = Channel.Create(ChannelDriver.Create(ChannelBridge.Create()));
        hub = Hub.Create(channel);

        //set a bpoint here, gets triggered
        // listen for when the Myo connects
        hub.MyoConnected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //set a bpoint here, doesn't get triggered
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                statusTbx.Text = "Myo has connected! " + e.Myo.Handle;
                //Console.WriteLine("Myo {0} has connected!", e.Myo.Handle);
                e.Myo.Vibrate(VibrationType.Short);

            }));
        };

        // listen for when the Myo disconnects
        hub.MyoDisconnected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                statusTbx.Text = "Myo has disconnected!";
                //Console.WriteLine("Oh no! It looks like {0} arm Myo has disconnected!", e.Myo.Arm);
                e.Myo.Vibrate(VibrationType.Medium);
            }));
        };

        // start listening for Myo data
        channel.StartListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: At this line ` channel = Channel.Create(ChannelDriver.Create(ChannelBridge.Create()));` 
I get an error `cannot implicitly convert type 'MyoSharp.Communication.IChannel' to 'MyoSharp.Communication.Channel' are you missing a cast?` I also get same error for `IHub` on following line. Any idea why this is?

Comment: declare them as `IChannel channel; IHub hub;`, respectively.

Comment: I updated my answer to give more explanation about the cause and fix.

Comment: the above solution worked, but when I call I try to call an event handler the dispathcer code doesn't update the textbox, poseStatusTbx Do you have any idea what could be wrong? This is the complete question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953938/calling-the-pose-triggered-event-using-myo-arm-band

Comment: I'm trying to move this code to it's own class and create two methods instead, `connect` and `disconnect` but I'm not sure how t extract these to a method. 
I've posted a question about it here if you have any input:
http://goo.gl/ZOmDAa