# Calling the pose triggered event using Myo arm band

Tags: c#, wpf, events, dispatcher, myo

I'm developing a project in WPF using a Myo arm band which works so far in recognizing the device has connected and updates info to the textbox, but when I set up the event handler for recognizing if a pose is triggered the event never fires.

I debugged this by making poses with the device and holding them, also I set a break point on this line `pose.Triggered += Pose_Triggered;` and the start of the pose triggered event.

The break point triggers on the first line where the but it doesn't trigger the breakpoint on the actual event `private void Pose_Triggered(object sender, PoseEventArgs e)`

This is the C# wrapper I'm using for the project: https://github.com/tayfuzun/MyoSharp

Does anyone know why the event doesn't trigger although the poses are being made?

This is the method where `pose_triggered` is called and the event:

```
// listen for when the Myo connects
                hub.MyoConnected += (sender, e) =>
                {

                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        statusTbx.Text = "Myo has connected! " + e.Myo.Handle;
                        e.Myo.Vibrate(VibrationType.Short);

                        // unlock the Myo so that it doesn't keep locking between our poses
                        e.Myo.Unlock(UnlockType.Hold);

                        // setup for the pose we want to watch for
                        var pose = HeldPose.Create(e.Myo, Pose.Fist);


                        pose.Triggered += Pose_Triggered;
                        e.Myo.OrientationDataAcquired += Myo_OrientationDataAcquired;



                    }));

                };
```

Code for triggered event:

```
private void Pose_Triggered(object sender, PoseEventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                //need to measure abduction of arm from 0 to 180 degrees.
                poseStatusTbx.Text = "{0} arm Myo holding pose {1}" + e.Myo.Arm + e.Myo.Pose;

                pitch = pitchCentre;

            }));    
        }
```

Here is the complete code for the class:  http://hastebin.com/xinirugufo.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compare the [sample code from GitHub](https://github.com/tayfuzun/MyoSharp) and your. Did you forget to call `pose.Start()`?

```
var pose = HeldPose.Create(e.Myo, Pose.Fist);
pose.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5); 
pose.Start(); //this???
pose.Triggered += Pose_Triggered;
```

Comment: I will test when I get home and let you know the result.